# Parse dynamic String input into LINQ query

Tags: linq

I need to build the query tree from the user input.

The query from the UI shall be like below and it will be dynamic.

for example:

```
(
    (
        (subject in ("facebook", "glassdoor")) 
        AND (date > "2020-01-01" AND date < "2020-05-31")
    ) 
    OR (from == "mike") 
    OR ((attachment == "pdf") OR ((attachment == "xls*"))
)
```

Need to convert this string into LINQ query.

If there is any other better approach there, please let me know.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take look at [System.Dynamic.Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) it may help you

Comment: You could also look at [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to help you build up queries from pieces. Do you have a formal grammar for your query language?